# Java - Spring - Call method with generic parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics

I'm trying to create a service similiar to this example that fetches data. Since the `GenreType` can be anything I created a `Registry` that maps each `GenreType` to a specific class.

Ignore the obvious flaw on this example of not being possible to have movies with the same type and the naming not being the most correct but it's just a example to show my problem.

Then I'm levaring `Spring` to fill this registry but the issues comes when I call the method `getData()`. It's expecting `A extends Genre` and I'm passing a `Genre` so it fails to compile.

Is there a better approach to this?

Thanks

```
pubic enum GenreType 
{
    ACTION,
    COMEDY
}

public interface Genre 
{
}

public class ActionMovie implements Genre
{
}

public class ComedyMovie implements Genre
{
}

public interface Movie<A extends Genre>
{
    MovieData getData( A genre );

    GenreType getType();
}

@Service
public class Borat implements Movie<ComedyMovie>
{
    public MovieData getData( ComedyMovie genre )
    {
         //...
    }


    @Override
    public GenreType getType() 
    {
        return GenreType.COMEDY;
    }
}

@Service
public class MovieRegistry
{
    private final Map<GenreType, Movie<?>> movies = new EnumMap<>( GenreType.class );

    public MovieRegistry( List<Movie<?>> movies )
    {
        movies .forEach( movie -> this.movies.putIfAbsent( movie.getType(), movie ) );
    }

    public Movie<?> get( GenreType genreType )
    {
        return movies.get( genreType );
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MovieService
{
    private final MovieRegistry movieRegistry;

    public MovieData get( GenreType type, Genre genre)
    {
         Movie<?> movie = movieRegistry.get(type);
         return movie.getData( genre ); //Problem here
    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried to generify the `MovieService.get()` method? `public <A extends Genre>  MovieData get( GenreType type, A genre)`. Hmm... but there might be still the problem with return type of `movieRegistry.get`

Comment: Yes, makes no difference.